# Deleting Visible Rows Takes too long to Process

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the below function which gives an option to Select the Range and then Delete all visible rows. This function is fine if I work on small datasets.

But nowadays I am working on Large Datasets with a number of columns and 400 to 500K rows. There are some dump data that I filtered out and delete using the below function.

**Is there any way to make it more efficient and faster.**

I do hope there can be a much better way of doing this. Your help will be appreciated.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Application.Selection

Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select one Range that you want to delete visible rows", "DeleteAllVisibleRows", myRange.Address, Type:=8)

myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated my question. Is there any way to make it more effieicent and faster.

Comment: Faster? For *400 to 500K rows*? I'm sure it's not possible with this tool (Excel). You can only slightly reduce the execution time of this line of code if you modify the .ScreenUpdating, .Calculation, .EnableEvents, .DisplayPageBreaks, .DisplayStatusBar, .DisplayAlerts properties of the Application object, but don't count on much success - 500K rows is really a lot.

Comment: Do you mean that you use `AutoFilter` to filter a table (one row of headers, not an Excel table) and you delete whatever got filtered, i.e. you want to delete the range `ws.AutoFilterRange.Resize(ws.AutoFilterRange.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`? If not, try to describe with a practical example or two, how you plan on using it.

Comment: NO there is no need to filter the table or data using VBA code i can do it by myself but i need to delete the visible rows as above my function is performing to delete the visible rows.

Comment: @ShRa Well, please answer the clarifying question - how do you set Invisible to the rows that should remain in the table? Do you use a filter and select by condition the records that need to be deleted? Or do you select the rows that should remain and execute the [**Hide**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hide-or-show-rows-or-columns-659c2cad-802e-44ee-a614-dde8443579f8) command for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I understood the reason for such a slow work of your program.

If @VBasic2008 is correct, and you are indeed using a filter to conditionally select some rows to delete, then the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`  method returns a range that consists of many distinct areas. To clear such a range, Excel actually cleans every single area and it takes a very long time.

You can cheat and pre-process the data for deletion, combine them into one continuous range. In this case, Excel should handle much faster:

```
Sub SortRngAndDelVisibleRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, indexRange As Range, delRange As Range, oCell As Range
Dim iCountToRest As Long, iCountToDel As Long
Dim oldDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    oldDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set sourceRange = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Resize(ws.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
Rem Thanks @VBasic2008 for a simple way to select the entire autofilter body.
Rem Let's create an auxiliary column next to the processed range
Rem and fill its invisible cells with row numbers.
    Set indexRange = sourceRange.Offset(0, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
    indexRange.Clear
    For Each oCell In indexRange.Cells
Rem Visible cells are skipped and left blank (we'll count it later)
        If oCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then oCell.Value = oCell.Row
    Next oCell
Rem (It would be possible to set any value, but the row numbers will allow
Rem you to keep the order of the records during subsequent sorting)    
    iCountToDel = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(indexRange)
    iCountToRest = sourceRange.Rows.Count - iCountToDel
    
Rem Disable the filter and sort the range in ascending order of values in the auxiliary column.
Rem Now all records without a number will be at the end of the set.
    If ws.FilterMode = True Then ws.ShowAllData
    sourceRange.Resize(, sourceRange.Columns.Count + 1).Sort _
        key1:=indexRange.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
Rem Now it can be deleted
Rem Since the rows to be deleted are now in the same contiguous range,
Rem the deletion process is much faster.
    Set delRange = sourceRange.Resize(iCountToDel).Offset(iCountToRest, 0)
    delRange.Rows.Delete
Rem Or it can be just cleared - the result should be the same
'    delRange.Clear
Rem The auxiliary range is also no longer needed
    indexRange.Clear
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = oldDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

Please try it

Comment: Thank you for the solution. i do not need to filter the range using code i can filter it manually but i jusr need to delete the visible rows using VBA.

Comment: @ShRa I didn't write that this code FILTERS, no. You are still selecting records manually, the macro only deletes visible rows, but it does it a little faster than `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete`

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnSUN first i was unable to understand it then i tried hard and got it. this is great one that i have.

Answer (score 0):

The cost comes from refreshing the Excel sheet in real-time.

Change the code to include `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to prevent the sheet from dynamically updating as it runs.

Comment: I trid but it still taking long time for priocessing